# AppleClang: Operator Overloading Compilation Error

Tags: c++, xcode, operator-overloading, clang

I implemented operator overloading as follows (see the methods `bool operator==` and `bool operator<`):

```
#include "../data_types.h"

class OffsetValuePair {
private:
    unsigned_value offset;
    unsigned_value value;

public:
    OffsetValuePair(unsigned_value address, unsigned_value value) {
        this->offset = address;
        this->value = value;
    }

    bool operator==(const OffsetValuePair offsetValuePair) {
        return this->getOffset() == offsetValuePair.offset;
    }

    bool operator<(const OffsetValuePair offset_value_pair) {
        return this->getValue() < offset_value_pair.value;
    }

    unsigned_value getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }

    unsigned_value getValue() {
        return value;
    }
};
```

I'm using the operator for finding the lower bound using will use my overloaded operator for less than (`<`):

```
const auto lower_bound_offset_value_pair = OffsetValuePair(0, 1234);
const auto lower_bound = std::lower_bound(pointer_map_sorted_by_value_.begin(),
                                                  pointer_map_sorted_by_value_.end(),
                                                  lower_bound_offset_value_pair);
```

When I compile the code, I get the following error with `AppleClang`:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:719:71: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const OffsetValuePair' and 'const OffsetValuePair')
    bool operator()(const _T1& __x, const _T1& __y) const {return __x < __y;}
                                                                  ~~~ ^ ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:4285:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__less<OffsetValuePair, OffsetValuePair>::operator()' requested here
        if (__comp(*__m, __value_))
            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:4307:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__lower_bound<std::__1::__less<OffsetValuePair, OffsetValuePair> &, std::__1::__wrap_iter<OffsetValuePair *>, OffsetValuePair>' requested here
    return __lower_bound<_Comp_ref>(__first, __last, __value_, __comp);
           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:4316:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::lower_bound<std::__1::__wrap_iter<OffsetValuePair *>, OffsetValuePair, std::__1::__less<OffsetValuePair, OffsetValuePair> >' requested here
    return _VSTD::lower_bound(__first, __last, __value_,
                  ^
/Users/bully/Desktop/PointerSearcher/src/pointer_search_objects/PointerSearcher.h:660:33: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::lower_bound<std::__1::__wrap_iter<OffsetValuePair *>, OffsetValuePair>' requested here
                const auto lower_bound = std::lower_bound(pointer_map_sorted_by_value_.begin(),
                                              ^
/Users/bully/Desktop/PointerSearcher/src/pointer_search_objects/OffsetValuePair.h:21:7: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const OffsetValuePair', but method is not marked const
        bool operator<(const OffsetValuePair offset_value_pair) {
             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:572:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'pair<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator< (const pair<_T1,_T2>& __x, const pair<_T1,_T2>& __y)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:702:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator<(const reverse_iterator<_Iter1>& __x, const reverse_iterator<_Iter2>& __y)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1143:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'move_iterator<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator<(const move_iterator<_Iter1>& __x, const move_iterator<_Iter2>& __y)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1512:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '__wrap_iter<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator<(const __wrap_iter<_Iter1>& __x, const __wrap_iter<_Iter2>& __y) _NOEXCEPT_DEBUG
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:1187:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'tuple<type-parameter-0-0...>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator<(const tuple<_Tp...>& __x, const tuple<_Up...>& __y)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2920:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'unique_ptr<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator< (const unique_ptr<_T1, _D1>& __x, const unique_ptr<_T2, _D2>& __y)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2978:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'unique_ptr<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator<(const unique_ptr<_T1, _D1>& __x, nullptr_t)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2987:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'unique_ptr<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator<(nullptr_t, const unique_ptr<_T1, _D1>& __x)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4758:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'shared_ptr<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator<(const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __x, const shared_ptr<_Up>& __y) _NOEXCEPT
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4823:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'shared_ptr<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator<(const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __x, nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4831:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'shared_ptr<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'const OffsetValuePair'
operator<(nullptr_t, const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __x) _NOEXCEPT
```

Using `gcc` and `MSVC` the code compiles fine, I'm only getting this error on `Mac OS X` with the standard platform compiler (`AppleClang`).

I do not understand why `AppleClang` does not accept the code. What is wrong with it?

I cannot declare the methods `const` since they use a `this` referenced method call. If I convert the `this` object into a 2nd method argument I get another error telling me that the method signature is wrong: error: `'bool OffsetValuePair::operator<(OffsetValuePair, OffsetValuePair)' must have exactly one argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found the solution:

```
bool operator==(const OffsetValuePair offsetValuePair) const {
    return this->offset == offsetValuePair.offset;
}

bool operator<(const OffsetValuePair offset_value_pair) const {
    return this->value < offset_value_pair.value;
}
```

The changes were to define both methods as `const` as suggested by the error message. Furthermore, when using the `this` reference method calls are not allowed due to the `const` method definition so I replaced the getter with the direct member access.